# CORS header Allow-Origin missing in POST requests

Tags: api, http, go, post, cors

I know there are tons of CORS related questions but I can't seem to find the answer to this one.

This is my server side golang code (We are using github.com/rs/cors go module):
We basically have set of apis that require an authorization header and some apis that don't (think checkout vs checkout as guest functionality)

```
allowedOrigins := []string{"http://localhost:3000", "http://localhost:3001"}
//allowedHeaders := []string{"Authorization"}
c := cors.New(cors.Options{AllowedOrigins: allowedOrigins, AllowCredentials: true})
handler := c.Handler(r)
```

What i found is the following:

```
// if allowcredentials is set to true, then all non auth requests go through but all auth requests return cors error

// if allowedHeaders: authorization is set then all **authenticated and NON authenticated** POST requests fail. GET works fine for both cases.
```

More specifically: The error I get is that AllowedOrigins is not set (??.. I get this in the PRE-FLIGHT OPTIONS response headers) when I try to execute a POST request and I set the AllowedHeaders:authorization option above.

If I comment that line (As you see above) then the non auth requests go through perfectly and the AllowedOrigins hader is sent back in the OPTIONS request..

Comment: What Allowed-Origin value is the server returning?

Comment: None.. It's actually not giving anything... but, when I set the AllowCredentials:true for example and I make a non authenticated call then I can see AllowOrigin:localhost... However, if i send an authenticated call (Auhtorization header bearer token) then AllowOrigin is not sent back by server.... its sort as if the server did not understand when i sent authorization: bearer ey... from client

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it....

```
https://github.com/rs/cors
```

Has a nice `CorsOptions Debug:true`. I used that to inspect what was going on and the moment i hardcoded that I allowed Authorization to come into my server then the POST request was complaining afterwards because I was also sending content-type (automatically sent by client (axios), I didn't specify it).. and Server was saying pretty much "I only recognize authorization header"... I added `Content-Type` and it now works!

```
allowedHeaders := []string{"Authorization", "Content-Type"}
```

Comment: Please accept your own answer to mark your problem as resolved.